# Need to read a URL and save the response as a file on the same server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I need to have a page on my website that when opened will read another URL address and capture the response from it (it's actually XML data responding) and then save that data on that same webservr to a file called DATA.XML

It needs to overwrite any file that is already there.

I only have ASP.NET available to me as a progrmming language.

Can someone show me how to do this in a ASP page.

Comment: What have you tried already? What are your problems? Where are you stuck? SO is for programming questions, not to ask "Can you please program me XYZ". We can help you out and give you pointers, but you have to come up with a concrete question.

Comment: _I only have ASP.NET available to me as a progrmming language. Can someone show me how to do this in a ASP page._  ok. which is it? ASP.Net or ASP? it's *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so something like?

1. Get the response from the other URL in to strResult.

   ```
   WebResponse objResponse;
   WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
   objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
   {
     strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
     sr.Close();
   }
   return strResult;
   ```
2. Use System.IO to save the strResult to a file (you can look that up as its pretty common code)

Comment: Thank you Christian for your help, it's good to know I can count on some people here to help out a non-programmer when they are stuck. I'll look up the System.IO for the save. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Google ASP.Net Write text to a file.  Also bear in mind that the folder you write to will need to have write access